# Arduino Serial debugging in live hardware

Tags: arduino

I have a strange issue with one of my wifi based projects where the entire loop seems to slow down and take 5 seconds to respond (it has an embedded web server).

I have serial debugging commands in my code, but when the code is running on the target hardware, there is nothing connected to the serial monitor.  Could that cause me an issue?  Should all Serial commands be commented out prior to final deployment and if they should is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do your serial pins are used for any connection ?
if yes, then you have to commented out the serial commands that do not related to the connected hardware.
If no , then there is no need. it just consumes some microseconds of your operation time.